# Do multi variable bracketing techniques exist to find root?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, numerical-methods, newton-raphson

I have been researching the classic bracketing optimization techniques like Bisection, Secant, Dekker and Brent method; however, none seem to have an application in multi variable calculus. Only Secant's method has been generalized in a multi variable setting, called Broyden's method; however, it uses a Secant-like method to approximate the Jacobian and subsequently applies Newton's method using this Jacobian approximation and thus does not really qualify as a bracketing method.

I have been approximating the root of a multivariable function $f(x)=(f_{1}(x_{1},...,x_{n}),...,f_{n}(x_{1},...,x_{n}))=0$ using multi variable Newton's method; however, I need to bracket the root with certainty in a multi variable setting.

Does anyone know an applicable bracketing technique in a multi variable setting or knows how to safely bracket a multi variable function after applying Newton's method?

Comment: Maybe [Interval arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic) is what you're looking for?

Comment: FYI - Dekker, Brent, Broyden, and Newton are the names of people who came up with the methods in question. Which is why we call them "Dekker's, Brent's, Broyden's, and Newton's methods", because they are the methods belonging to these people. "Bisection" and "Secant" are not people but mathematical concepts associated with those methods. There is no possession here. So it is called the "Secant method", not "Secant's method".

Answer (score 1):

By bracketing in every component, one is able to iteratively solve more and more components at a time.

---

#### Example

Consider the following function:

$$f(x,y)=(x^2+y-1,y^2-2x-1).$$

---

#### Brackets

We can then see that for all $y\in[-3,-1.5]$,

$$0\in[f_1(1.5,y),f_1(2,y)]=[y+1.25,y+3],$$

and for all $x\in[1.5,2]$,

$$0\in[f_2(x,-1.5),f_2(x,-3)]=[1.25-2x,8-2x].$$

This means for $x\in\{1.5,2\}$, we can always find $y\in[-3,-1.5]$ where $f_1=0$, and for $y\in\{-3,-1.5\}$, we can always find $x\in[1.5,2]$ where $f_2=0$.

---

#### Solving

I would suggest drawing a diagram while going through the following steps, and taking note of the signs of $f_1$ and $f_2$ along the boundaries of $[1.5,2]\times[-3,-1.5]$.

Now fix $y_0=-3$ and solve for $x_0$ via bracketing from $f_1$:

$$f_1(1.5\le x_0\le2,-3)=0\implies x_0=\dots$$

Similarly fix $y_1=-1$ and solve for $x_1$ via bracketing from $f_1$:

$$f_1(1.5\le x_1\le2,-1.5)=0\implies x_1=\dots$$

Now we have $f(x_0,y_0)=(0,+) $ and $f(x_1,y_1)=(0,-)$. We then choose a new $y_0<y_2<y_1$ and repeat to solve for $x_2$:

$$f_1(1.5\le x_2\le2,y_2)=0\implies x_2=\dots$$

Now we have $f(x_2,y_2)=(0,?)$, where the sign of $f_2(x_2,y_2)$ determines which of $y_0$ or $y_1$ you should keep for the next iteration.

---

Such a process is tedious, especially as the number of dimensions increases, but it does show that multivariate bracketing methods are possible. I'm certain there are better approaches, but I have not seen that much concerning the topic in the literature.

Comment: Your first statement does not hold for $y=-1$. Furthermore, this is not true in general, as for $f=(\exp(-x)*\exp(-y)-0.5,f_{2})$ on the domain $[0,0.5]\times[0,1]$, there is no root for $f_{1}$ when fixing for $y=0$ or $y=1$.

Comment: You have to account for the effect that when moving in all dimensions simultaneously the root might be crossed

Comment: Fixed the bracket for the example.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding the bracket you're trying to use, your counterexample isn't valid, since for $y=0$, one eould have $f_1(0,y)$ and $f_1(0.5,y)$ share the same sign.

Comment: As far as proof of convergence to a root, note that we can always solve for $x$ s.t. $f_2(x,y)=0$ due to bracketing with $1.5\le x\le2$. Let this solution be $x=r(y)$. Then the larger step is just bracketing $f_1(r(y),y)$ with $-3\le y\le-1.5$.